# Copying only selected group membership to a new user

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to finish this script, but I keep getting an error at line:5 char:39.

I want to be able to copy someone's Member Of Groups to another user by selecting which groups I want to copy on a pop-up window.

```
$ad1 = Get-ADUser test1 -Properties memberof
$ad2 = Get-ADUser test2 -Properties memberof
$MissingGroups = Compare-Object $ad1 $ad2 -Property memberof
$GroupsObj = $MissingGroups.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup –prop Description | Select Name,Description
$GroupsObj | Out-GridView -PassThru | Add-ADGroupMember -members $ad2
```

Comment: ... What error?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you on your feet.
Problem was that you weren't getting the groups as individual objects. Tested this on my own account and it works like a charm. Never thought to do this, gonna keep this in my back pocket now.

```
$user1 = "test1"
$user2 = "test2"
$ad1 = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user1 | select Name
$ad2 = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user2 | select Name
$MissingGroups = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ad1 -DifferenceObject $ad2 -Property name
$GroupsObj = $MissingGroups.Name | Get-ADGroup -Properties Description | Select Name,Description
$GroupsObj | Out-GridView -PassThru | ForEach-Object{Add-ADGroupMember $_.Name -Members $user1}
```

Comment: So awesome Drew!! This is definitely on the right path! However, noticed it errors out with distribution list groups. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey @MrGlobalHD , What is the error you are receiving? Errors allow us to narrow down the exact cause.